# Data binding using radio buttons and Web UI

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I cannot get the following code for data-binding using radio inputs to work:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name='veggies' value="kale" bind-value={{name}}>Kale<br>
      <input type="radio" name='veggies' value="spinach" bind-value={{name}}>Spinach<br>
      <input type="radio" name='veggies' value="carrots" bind-value={{name}}>Carrots
    </div>

    <p>name = {{name}}</p>

    <script type="application/dart">

      import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

      @observable
      String name = "Carrots";

      void main() {}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The file is radio_binding.html.

When I build this file, I get an error in the out/radio_binding.html.dart file:

```dart
Error: line 42 pos 46: semicolon expected
  __t.listen(__e0.onChange, ($event) { {{name}} = 'kale'; });
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not a Dart user, but doesn't your `bind-value` attribute need to be enclosed in quotes? i.e. it should be `bind-value="{{name}}"` ?

Comment: Come on over Dai!  I'd love to learn from/collaborate on some bit magic stuff w/ you as SIMD for Dart rolls out more features :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this binding:

```dart
<div>
  <input type="radio" name='veggies' value="Kale" bind-value="name">Kale<br>
  <input type="radio" name='veggies' value="Spinach" bind-value="name">Spinach<br>
  <input type="radio" name='veggies' value="Carrots" bind-value="name">Carrots
</div>
```

And I don't think you need the @observable, I just used:

```dart
String name = 'Spinach';
```

Comment: Side note, the values ARE case sensitive so "Carrots" wont match "carrots"

Comment: Of course, changing the {{ }} after the bind-value to "" fixes the problem. Many thanks.  Also, yes, this works without @observable, but Web UI is moving away from the old way of data-binding with watchers, and towards using \@observable. So, if I am not mistaken, this is the preferred way of data-binding now. It is not terribly well documented, unfortunately.